# Syncronize Gradle Projects with workspace failed error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build.gradle

my application is in java and the IDE used is Eclipse.
I am facing below mentioned issue on refreshing my gradle project.

**[Cannot nest
'MyApp-Service/src/test/java/com/mycompany/mymodule/myservice/functional' inside 'MyApp-Service/src/test/java'. To enable the nesting exclude 'com/' from 'MyApp-Service/src/test/java']**

here is my folder structure

**main folder structure**

MyApp-Service/src/main/java/com/mycompany/mymodule/myservice/controller

**test folder structure**

MyApp-Service/src/test/java/com/mycompany/mymodule/myservice/functional

Below is my build.gradle code snipet

```
sourceSets {
    functionalTest {
        java {
            srcDir file('src/test/java/com/mycompany/mymodule/myservice/functional')
        }
      }
    }
```

Most confusing part is if i set the funtionalTest gradle source dir to any other path even if give some junk path the gradle builds fine.
For eg

```
sourceSets {
functionalTest {
    java {
        srcDir file('NotAvalidPath')
         }
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve the issue . Thanks in advance.